# Angular Material Mat-Chip validation in template driven form

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-validation, angular-material-6

I am using Angular 6 with Angular Material 6. I want to required the mat-chip field. When i input mat-chip field then the save button will be enable otherwise will be disabled. The input field is required but can not able to require the mat-chip field. Please help me to find the solution. Thanks.

My sample code link here: [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-chip-validation?file=app%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts)

Comment: why don't you use ng-chips?
git repo: https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips 
demo: https://angular-mfppay.stackblitz.io/ 

It stores the items in an array, so you can easily validate the save button with the length of an array. Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try ngx-chips in later.

Comment: Are you mixing template driven forms and reactive forms?  That seems to be reason - your "fruits" is not showing in the form - you can try this by displaying `{{ sampleForm.form .value | json }}  ` in your template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your save button you can use disabled property that you already have but that should be something like this:

```
[disabled]="company_name === undefined || fruits.length === 0"
```

### For other people coming for this question:

There's another great package that you can use which gives you validations for your tags and it goes by the name of **ng-chips**.

**Git Repo**: github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips

**Online Demo**: angular-mfppay.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1):

[Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-chip-validation-zzaeqx)

HTML:

```
<form #sampleForm="ngForm">

    <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
        <input matInput placeholder="Company Name" required="true" name="company_name" [(ngModel)]="company_name">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
        <mat-chip-list #chipList>
            <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
                {{fruit}}
                <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
            </mat-chip>
            <input placeholder="New fruit..." #fruitInput [formControl]="fruitCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
             [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
        </mat-chip-list>
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
                {{fruit}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>


    <button fxFlex="30" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!sampleForm.form.valid || company_name === undefined || fruits.length === 0">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i have solved this by another answer before your answer posting. it's same answer. thanks